# How can I create a multi stage pipeline using spark streaming similar to storm?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-storm

I am thinking on how I can create a multi stage(graph based topology) streaming application using spark streaming similar to storm.

In storm we have this concept of spouts, bolts and we can chain these concepts to form a graph, with different kinds of bolts chained together to perform different tasks. The bolts/spouts can be performing their work independently passing the results further downstream.

How can I achieve something similar using spark streaming? I mean in spark it's basically RDD transforming. How can I achieve something similar so that I have different processing components performing their tasks independently(something like a workflow)

In spark, I can do something like this

rdd.map(some map function).map(some other map function) and so on to chain the tasks together. But here the driver is blocked until the whole processing is complete before it can start processing the second set of data batch. I want it to be something like a workflow. Is it possible in spark?

Answer (score 0):

Spark has Transformation-Reduction architecture and Storm has DAG architecture. This is not a good idea to develop conventional programs which runs by Storm on Spark. You must **think different** when work with spark.

Spark by default send tuples to processors (Mappers) like **fieldsGrouping** or **Partial Key grouping** which is spread out by a key.

However, you can simulate some Storm operations on Spark. For example for `Spout -> BoltA -> BoltB` all with `fieldsGrouping` you can do:

```
//streamEvents  is equal to Spout
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> streamEvents = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);

JavaPairDStream<String, Object> newKeys1 = streamEvents.flatMapToPair(x->BoltA);
JavaPairDStream<String, Object> newKeys2 = newKeys1.flatMapToPair(x->BOltB);
```

If you want `Spout->BoltA , Spout->BoltB` you can do:

```
//streamEvents  is equal to Spout
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> streamEvents = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);

JavaPairDStream<String, Object> newKeys1 = streamEvents.flatMapToPair(x->BoltA);
JavaPairDStream<String, Object> newKeys2 = streamEvents.flatMapToPair(x->BOltB);
```

for **Global grouping** you must set a keyValue pair and the key must be equal in all inputs.

I don't recommend using Spark instead of Storm with the same architecture. Try to adapt with Spark or use Storm in some special cases.